# Monitorix Graphs Show Boxes Where Text Should Be

Tags: lighttpd, network-monitoring, cgi, rrdtool, arch-linux

I have just installed **Monitorix** on **ArchLinux** using the tutorial here: *wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Monitorix*

I am using the **Lighttpd** web server.

It is working fine and the graphs are being generated, but instead of text on the graphs its replaced by 'boxes' like the language  is missing or something. See picture here:

*Picture of bad graphs*: http://cl.ly/99929108eeabf3ed72da/

My **/etc/monitorix.conf** file is using "en" as the laungage:

```
# General
our $TITLE = "Hodge Inc.";              # your company name
our $HOSTNAME = "hodge-fs";             # hostname of this server
our $OSTYPE = "Linux-Arch";             # choose your OS type (see below)
our $SAMBAVER = "3";                    # Samba version (2 or 3)
our $MULTIHOST = "N";                   # Enable multihost feature
our $MULTIHOST_FOOTER = "N";            # (multihost) display URL in image
our $MULTIHOST_IMGPERLINE = "2";        # (multihost) # of images per line
our $REPORT_LANG = "en";                # Report language
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing the **terminus-font** package.

I also updated the ArchLinux wiki here: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Monitorix

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem also. terminus-font don't fix my problem. After some check, it say somewhere online, this related missing mono font.

So, my solution is that, first check font list with

```
fc-list
```

On my system, this show empty fc-list. It need install some mono font by doing following command

```
apt-get install fonts-inconsolata fonts-freefont-otf fonts-freefont-ttf  fonts-jura  fonts-tlwg-mono
fc-list :spacing=mono
```

This time it show some mono font. Not all four fonts should use. Only one should be enough.

After restart monitorix and clean existing picture. It works, cheer!